# Is this how Type Theory works?

Tags: type-theory

I'm trying to understand (Intuitionistic) Type Theory but getting nowhere fast. Can you tell me if I got this right?

So my proposition is that there exist a natural number whose square is 9.

So in set theory I might write:

$$\exists x \in \mathbb{N}: x^2=9$$

Now in Type Theory, is there is a type called "Proof that there exists a number whose square is 9"? And all proofs are of this type? And presumably a proof consists of constructing an element of this type from some axioms. How would you do it in this case when for example just showing that $x=3$ proves the above statement? In set theory you would just build this statement starting from some axioms. (How is this different to Type Theory?)

And for Fermat's Last Theorem is there a type called "Proof of Fermat's Last Theorem" and all proofs are of this type?

Apart from the language is Type Theory more-or-less the same as set theory? (I heard the Axiom of Choice is a theorem in Type Theory not an Axiom.)

Can you give an example of a simple proof in type theory?

As far as I can tell type theory seems to be the same as set theory buy just avoiding circularity and with different words. Is that right?

Comment: It would probably help if you state *which* type theory you're working with. There are many different ones; the term names more a general complex of ideas than any songle concrete system.

Comment: It depends on what kind of type theory you're considering. Some type theories have propositions-as-types and so yes, a proof of a statement is a construction of an object of the type of the statement; e.g. here a proof of $\exists x : \mathbb N, x^2=9$ would be a pair $(3,p)$ where $p$ is a proof of $3^2=9$ (which would probably actually be just $refl_9$ as $3^2$ can be computed judgmentally)

Comment: You don't get places fast in mathematics. You get there ***very*** slowly.

Comment: @Asaf Yep. True. But this type theory stuff is going over my head. String theory is simpler!

Comment: @Max so would a proof be built up from lemmas built from axioms like $(L_1,L_2,L_3,L_4)$ and then there are some rules to reduce the type into a simpler form to show it is equal to the type of the problem? e.g. Something of type $(A\implies B, B \implies C)$ is reduced to type $(A \implies C)$?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying but in any case it will depend on the specific type theory. Some type theories don't have axioms per se, they only have inference rules

Comment: @Max Propositions-as-types is more a way of viewing/using a type theory. You could treat the Simply Typed Lambda Calculus (STLC) as a sort of equational theory which is what HOL does giving you a powerful higher-order logic, or you could take a propositions-as-types view of it in which case it corresponds to (a fragment of) intuitionistic propositional logic. It's the STLC either way though.

Comment: Are you already aware of "From Set Theory to Type Theory", by Mike Shulman (https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html)? If not, you might find it helpful. As Shulman notes in that post, one distinction between set theory and type theory is that, whereas a set theory like ZFC is *built on top of* First-Order Logic (FOL), type theories don't "require the imposing superstructure of connectives, quantifiers, and inference to be built up before we start to state axioms ... first-order logic in type theory is just a special case of the type-forming rules."